# Converting text from first person to second person with issues ignoring text within quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, google-colaboratory

I am trying to convert stories/sentences/words/etc from first person to second person grammer, but trying to not convert text within quotes " " or ' '.

It reads a file from google drive and makes it a string. 'forms = {..}' is the list of words to convert. It converts the words, and ignores words within quotations.

```
import nltk
import re
from google.colab import drive
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer

drive.mount('/content/drive')

sent = open('/content/drive/My Drive/storyuno.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") 
quote_re = re.compile(r'["“”]')  

forms = {"am" : "are", "are" : "am", 'i' : 'you', 'my' : 'yours', 'me' : 'you', 'mine' : 'yours', 'you' : 'I', 'your' : 'my', 'yours' : 'mine'} # More?

def translate(word):
  if word.lower() in forms: return forms[word.lower()]
  return word

translated = []
quote_mode = False
for word in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent.read()):
   if quote_mode:
       translated.append(word)
       if quote_re.search(word): quote_mode = False;

   if not quote_mode:
       translated.append(translate(word))
   if quote_re.search(word): quote_mode = True;


result = ' '.join(translated)
detokenizer = TreebankWordDetokenizer()
result = detokenizer.detokenize(translated)

print(result) 
sent.close()
```

**The output text is:** 
The bottom line is that if you was going to tell anyone about the frog, it would be Soy . you decided that our walk home would be the most opportune time . “ Did you see anything outside today during math?”?” I asked Soy as we started walking . “ “ What do you mean? Like in the sky?”?” he asked, jumping over cracks in the sidewalk . “ “ I mean right outside the window . Like right up against it ,” ,” I answered . “ “ Like a person?”?” he asked, still hopping . Soy sat in the row farthest from the window, so it was possible, but unlikely, for someone to walk by without him noticing.

**Issue:** So the code converts text from first person to second person, except for words within quotations. However after identifying quotations, it adds " to the text when it sees ". It's also adding extra punctuation when it sees punctuation (? ! . , ). I need help with this issue.